# Variadic template trouble matching const and non-const std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm having trouble constructing a variadic template where the expansion functions properly match both a non-const and const `std::string`. I have a generic matching function which is called instead in some cases.

I've reduced the code to the below example. Things which aren't a string should end up at the generic function. Things which are a string should end up at the second function which additionally outputs "STRING".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename X, typename T>
void extend_exception( X & ex, T&& value )
{
    ex << value << std::endl;
}

template<typename X>
void extend_exception( X & ex, std::string && value )
{
    ex << "STRING: " << value << std::endl;
}

template<typename X, typename TF, typename ... TR>
void extend_exception( X & ex, TF&& f, TR&& ... rest )
{
    extend_exception( ex, std::forward<TF>(f) );
    extend_exception( ex, std::forward<TR>(rest)... );
}

int main()
{
    extend_exception( std::cout, std::string( "Happy" ) );
    std::string var( "var" );
    extend_exception( std::cout, var );
    extend_exception( std::cout, var, std::string( "Combo" ),  const_cast<std::string const&>(var));
    return 0;
}
```

In the version above the two `var` uses do not get passed to the string function. I have tried various other ways of specifying the parameter but none seem to do the trick: `std::string && value`, `std::string const & value`, `std::string const && value`.  I did also try just `std::string & value` and then the non-const strings match, but not the const ones. This provides me with at least a workaround by having two different functions, but I suspect I shouldn't need to do this.

How do I write a single function here that will be called for const, non-const, and temporary string objects?

*I'm using g++ 4.6.3*

Comment: Just passing by value seems to work, although I doubt it's anyhow "correct".

Comment: @Griwes, yes, by value works but I don't want to by copying things needlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revisited the problem and came up with a solution which involves using a class marker. I've written an article with the [full solution/discussion](http://mortoray.com/2013/06/03/overriding-the-broken-universal-reference-t/).

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty tricky, `T&&` is a so called universal reference but `std::string&&` is not (no type deduction is involved). See [here](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) for a good explanation.  Here is a fix:

```
template<typename X, typename T>
void extend_exception_( X & ex, T&& value, ... )
{
  ex << value << std::endl;
}

template<typename X, typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<
           std::is_same<std::string, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value>::type>
void extend_exception_( X & ex, T && value, int )
{
  ex << "STRING: " << value << std::endl;
}

template <typename T> using identity = T;

template<typename X, typename ... R>
void extend_exception( X & ex, R&& ... rest )
{
  identity<bool[]>{false,(extend_exception_(ex, std::forward<R>(rest), 0), false)...};
}

int main()
{
  extend_exception( std::cout, std::string( "Happy" ) );
  std::string var( "var" );
  extend_exception( std::cout, var );
  extend_exception( std::cout, var, std::string( "Combo" ) );
}
```

Comment: Defined 5 lines above it's usage: `identity` is the identity ;)

Comment: You probably want to use `std::decay` instead of `std::remove_reference` otherwise the `is_same` test fails for `const std::string`. Aternatively use `std::remove_cv` _and_ `std::remove_reference`, but `std::decay` is less typing and equivalent in this case.

Comment: I am unable to test this since template aliases aren't supported until GCC 4.7 (your identity declaration). Can you verify that my added parameter in my example (last call to extend_exception with a const_cast) still also works with this code?

Comment: Yeah, to get it right without SFINAE requires three functions for each specialized type (std::string here).  http://ideone.com/o3wxsl

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind a non-rvalue to an rvalue-reference, so `string&&` doesn't work, but `const std::string&` works for `var`. However, `var` is not const, so the shortest path to an overload that works is collapsing `T&&` to `std::string&` and taking the first one.

You'll need to figure out types that are mutually exclusive or use SFINAE to write two that exclude each other on the right type of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your string version only captures strings passed as rvalues. lvalues will get passed to the generic function. There is a huge difference between T&& and string&&, or more general T&& and U&&, if T is a template parameter and U is not (meaning, U is some specified type). See Scott Meyers' notes on [universal references](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

What you need to do in order to make the function work as you want is add yet another overload:

```
template<typename X>
void extend_exception( X & ex, std::string const& value )
{
  ex << "STRING: " << value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `&&` also won't catch mutable references.  You need to add _two_ other overloads.